# C++11 Random between int x, int y, excluding list<int>

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, random, std

I need a way to generate random integers between x,y, but once a random z is generated, I need the next iteration of x,y to exclude z (or better yet, a list of ints to exclude). The return value has to honor the "std::uniform_int_distribution<>" condition. There is an obvious way to do this, but I was hoping for a fast version.

```
int GenerateRandomBetweenExcluding(int min, int max, int exclude) // even better is a list<int> to exclude
{
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen(rd());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> dis(min, max); // how to exclude "exclude" or list<int>?

    int randNum = dis(gen);

    return randNum;
}
```

Comment: randomize between `min` and `max-1` If result >= `exclude`, add one

Comment: That changes the uniformnesss of the distribution, as the return values could bunch above exclude.

Comment: The obvious way being is to discard it if you come across it?

Comment: Of course! That is horribly slow, although obviously works.

Comment: So you're looking for a random sample without duplicates, correct?

Comment: exacfly, but honoring std::uniform_int_distribution<> and as fast as possible.

Comment: if you just want no duplicates, maby `std::random_shuffle` is of help

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding how it can still be a uniform distribution if you start preventing duplicates.

Comment: @MarkB: uniform doesn't imply independent.  The prior distributions are each uniform, the conditional distributions aren't.

Comment: @MarkB, I just thought of that. I guess I mean evenly distributed between a,b without duplicates. I want it to use the constraint while generating the rand #, but alter it after the fact. See Ben's response.

Comment: @sp2danny, std::random_shuffle might be perfect. I see this, which seems to show that it honors uniform_distribution: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle

Comment: Completely side note: `std::list` is probably the wrong container to use.

Comment: `std::random_shuffle` is deprecated in C++14. Can `std::shuffle` do the trick?

Comment: @NickyC You should use `std::shuffle` anyway. `random_shuffle` either uses the crappy `rand()` or requires a really weird RNG interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <random>

class NoRepeat
{
public:
    void Init(int,int);
    int GetOne();
    bool HasMore();
private:
    std::vector<int> list;
};

void NoRepeat::Init(int min, int max) // min and max are inclusive
{
    list.clear();
    list.reserve(max-min+1);
    for( int i=min; i<=max; ++i )
        list.push_back(i);
    std::random_shuffle( list.begin(), list.end() );
    // might want to supply own random_func, default uses rand()
}

bool NoRepeat::HasMore()
{
    return !list.empty();
}

int NoRepeat::GetOne()
{
    int ret = list.back();
    list.pop_back();
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: -1 because code-only answer. Please consider explaining or showing a possible approach instead of *“plz send teh codez”*-like answer

Answer (score 1):

Use a list with all numbers between min and max. Choose randomly an element and delete it.

Comment: @JBL "So you're looking for a random sample without duplicates, correct?" - This is a one way to do that.

Comment: What if the list of possible numbers is enormous?

Comment: You can leave out all the elements of the list. The question is about integers, but you want to exclude type T elements?

Comment: The T part is a typo. Fixed

Answer (score 0):

There's a nice way to do this if your exclusion list is sorted in ascending order. You can achieve this sorting by using a `set<int>` instead of a `list<int>` to track exclusions; most set operations take `log(n)` time and the container is guaranteed to be sorted at all times.

The algorithm is as follows:

```
set<int> exclude;
/* ... configure generator and exclusion set ... */
uniform_int_distribution<> dis(min, max-exclude.size());
int val = dis(gen);

/* skip over the exclusions */
for(int i : exclude) {
    if(val >= i) val++;
    else break;
}
return val;
```